# How can I find which drivers are the correct ones for my machine?

Tags: drivers, wifi-driver, display-driver

I'm currently installing Windows 7 onto a new laptop before imaging it to deploy. I need to install the Wireless and Graphics drivers, but the HP site is offering me both ATI and Intel graphics drivers (at 102MB and 470(!)MB) a pop, as well as Intel, Broadcomm, RealTek and Atheros wireless drivers.

Is there a bit of software that will tell me what devices are in the machine so I don't have to go through, trial-and-error and find which is the right driver for the hardware?

Comment: The reason its offering both Intel and ATI graphic drivers is because your laptop has both a dedecated graphics card and one provided by your 2nd or 3rd generation i3,i5,i7 processor.

Comment: @Ramhound - it does?! I completely forgot about the i3 CPU having it's own graphics ability - these are the first ix laptops we have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the [HP Support Assistant](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareRedirector?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&softwareitem=ob-85373-1&docname=c00828604)
2. Click on `Maintain / Tune-up / Start Tune-up`
3. When the process is complete, a list of updated drivers and actions will be displayed and you just need to follow the on-screen instructions to apply all the Important and Recommended actions